# GridView Causing IE Script Error & Latency When Subordinated Within Master.Page

Tags: asp.net, gridview

GridView binding renders quickly on Default.aspx form...and is triggered by Bind() method from button event on default.aspx form. The data source is bound dynamically through SqlDataReader populating and returning IEnumerable object

```
<form runat="server">
     <asp:gridview runat="server" ID="GridView1"></asp:gridview>
 </form>
```

However, when trying to invoke same functionality from web form derived from master.page, IE returns script error and takes 30 seconds to return data that returns instantaneously in default.aspx. I will say on the subordinated web form the gridView is within Content tags and also using .css reference in Master.Page. Trying to get this site functionally and aesthetically appropriate and not look like a bare bones DOS-like screen.

Many thanks............